# Shell script to SUM and find MAX by grouping based on two columns

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I want to know if there is any simple approach to SUM a field based on group by of different fields

for e.g.
file1.txt contains below data

```
20160622|XXX1||50.00||50.00|MONEY|Plan1|
20160622|XXX1||100.00||100.00|MONEY|Plan1|
20160623|XXX1||25.00||25.00|MONEY|Plan1|
20160622|XXX2|||||MONEY|Plan4|
20160622|XXX3||20.00||20.00|MONEY|Plan5|
```

Now i want to 
group by based on COLUMN - 2,3,5,7,8
SUM the column 4,6
Get Max Date of Column 1

Output Expected :

```
20160623|XXX1||175.00||175.00|MONEY|Plan1|
20160622|XXX2|||||MONEY|Plan4|
20160622|XXX3||20.00||20.00|MONEY|Plan5|
```

Comment: How is column 1 grouped-by? doesn't make sense in your i/p and o/p and what did you try?

Comment: You may get more flexibility by using e.g. sqlite. You can write a bash script around sqlite fairly straightforwardly.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple but silly. Of course if you need it, it's not silly anymore. In AWK:

```
$ cat > grouper.awk
{
    max1[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8]=(max1[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8]>$1?max1[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8]:$1)
    sum4[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8]+=$4
    sum6[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8]+=$6
    a[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8]=max1[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8] OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS sum4[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8] OFS $5 OFS sum6[$2,$3,$5,$7,$8] OFS $7 OFS $8
} 
END {
    for(i in a) 
        print a[i]
}

$ awk -F\| -v OFS=\| -f grouper.awk file
20160622|XXX3||20||20|MONEY|Plan5
20160623|XXX1||175||175|MONEY|Plan1
20160622|XXX2||0||0|MONEY|Plan4
```

All sums must be summed in different arrays (you could use multidimensional arrays, of course) and the grouping is done in the array index.